Regarding REL label is restricted when we try to apply by using core view
**view **: cint_c1a_8ch_shift_RN_C1A_SHIFT
Label name: REL_C1A_SHIFT_SW_SOP_HWD01_SW04_V00_CGW_REN_NIS_C1A_8CH_SHIFT cint_c1a_8ch_shift_RN_C1A_SHIFT_3
config spec of view:
element lost+found -none
element /C1A_8CH_SHIFT/... .../cint_RN_C1A_SHIFT/LATEST
element /C1A_8CH_SHIFT/... MIP_C1A_SHIFT_BASE_CODE_HWC01_SW01_V00_CGW_REN_NIS_C1A_8CH_SHIFT -mkbranch cint_RN_C1A_SHIFT
element /C1A_8CH_SHIFT/... /main/0 -mkbranch cint_RN_C1A_SHIFT

config spec of Label which we have to apply:
element lost+found -none
element /C1A_8CH_SHIFT/... REL_C1A_SHIFT_SW_SOP_HWD01_SW04_V00_CGW_REN_NIS_C1A_8CH_SHIFT -nco

# 

# LIBRARY Section

# 

include \\eb_custom\\view_profiles\\ClearCase View Profiles\\C1A_8CH_SHIFT\\Normal_Structure\\LIB_include\\include_c1a_8ch_shift_00.cs

Why REL and MIP labels is restricted for that particular view?
I see in documented, it is saying that due to wrong branch it is restricted, as it is an old branch, but the label is newly created

